# GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs/ 404 (Not Found) in angular4

Tags: angular

node_modules/rxjs not found, while npm start my app.i have tried may of suggestions. not succeed. i am using quickstart repo form gihub [click](https://github.com/angular/quickstart)

My systemjs.config.js file

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'app': 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        meta: {
          './*.js': {
            loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
          }
        }
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
      });
    })(this);
```

my package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"polyfills": "^2.1.1",
"rxjs": "5.0.1",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
```

},

Tried many of the solutions from stackoverflow, didn't solved error.

Comment: And what static server?

Comment: what is the folder structure you are following

Comment: rxjs is there in your node_modules?

Comment: @Aravind yes it is there

Comment: @Aravind Thanks Aravind for same. but can't connect with using same

Comment: Could you post the file where you have used the rxjs as import ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Solved:** In systemjs.config.js
placed code:

```
rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        main: 'Rx.js'
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to tell the system how to load the reactive extensions for JS. Add the code below to the packages object in your system.config.js

```
packages: {
  ...
  rxjs: {
    main: 'Rx.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
  ...
}
```